# Is this code blocking Rails from serving other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am calling an external library from rails like this:

`%x( jasperstarter pr #{template_path} -f #{format} --data-file #{data_path} --xml-xpath #{xpath} -t xml -o #{output_path} )`

**My question is will this cause other request to the site to have to wait before this process is done? If so what are the ways I can mitigate this?**

Note: This code is being run in the admin side of the site to generate report, which ideally shouldn't interrupt the customer of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby thread running this command will block until the command is finished, so if you have a single web process with one thread handling all requests, yes, other requests will have to wait. You can avoid blocking other requests in many ways:

- Run more than one web process, so other requests can be handled outside of the process running this command.
- Run a concurrent webserver like [Puma](http://puma.io/) or [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), so this command only blocks one of the several threads the server runs to handle requests.
- Run the command in a background worker via a job queue like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).
- Run the command in another [Thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html) yourself.
- Run the command outside of a web process entirely, for example from a terminal or via `cron`.

Comment: Ideally, I would like it to behave like it is processing in the background, but the process is being run on the fly and the user is expecting the output back immediately. So I guess concurrent webserver seems like the way to go?

Comment: If you're triggering this via a web request and you want to respond immediately to the user, I'd recommend enqueueing the job into a background queue. Even with a concurrent webserver, though you're not blocking other requests, the request that triggered this command will still wait for it to finish.